# Relationship between logarithm and inverse-trig function

Tags: integration

I've come across this particular integral

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx $$

And I've confused it with the generic inverse secant integral given by

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}} dx $$

Where the second integral is:

$$ \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}} dx = \sec^{-1}(x) + C $$

While,

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx = \ln{x} - \ln{(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1)}+ C $$

But couldn't we do, say,

$$ \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}} dx = \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{(-1)(1-x^{2})}}dx  = \sec^{-1}(x) + C $$

So,

$$ -i \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}}dx  = \sec^{-1}(x) + C $$

Thus,

$$ \ln{x} - \ln{(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1)} = i\sec^{-1}(x) + C$$

But what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: As I was writing this question, I've realized the mistake in my reasoning, but I've decided to post anyways because even that could be wrong. The error is that $\sqrt{(-1)(1-x^2)}$ cannot be split into $i\sqrt{1-x^2}$. A common "fake-proof" thing, which shows $-1 = 1$ by equating $\sqrt{1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)}$ and $ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} =  \sqrt{(-1)} \sqrt{(-1)} = i^2 = -1$

Comment: The usual relationship is $i\sec^{-1}z=-\ln z+\ln(\sqrt{1-z^2}+1)$, which is the same as you have got except for a sign, which prob arose from the square root, as you say. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: @almagest oh what... really?

Answer (score 1):

The integral in question is $$\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=-\operatorname{arsech}{\left|x\right|}+C$$ where $\operatorname{arsech}{x}$ is the inverse hyperbolic secant function and the other integral is $$\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}}=\operatorname{arcsec}{\left|x\right|}+C$$ where $\operatorname{arcsec}{x}$ is the inverse secant function.

Recall that the cosine function and the hyperbolic cosine function are related by $\cos{ix}=\cosh{x}$ and $\cosh{ix}=\cos{x}$. Since secant is the reciprocal of cosine, secant and hyperbolic secant are related by $\sec{ix}=\operatorname{sech}{x}$ and $\operatorname{sech}{ix}=\sec{x}$. Plug in $x=\operatorname{sech}{t}$ or $x=\sec{t}$ to see the relation between their inverses.

In terms of logarithms, the inverse hyperbolic secant is $$\operatorname{arsech}{x}=\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)}$$ and the inverse secant is $$\operatorname{arcsec}{x}=-i\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}+i\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)}$$